# My CSS animations are not working in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, css-animations

Please have a look at http://facelesstolegendary.com

I looked at several posts here and saw that I need to add the `-webkit-` prefix to my transforms, etc.

I did that, but it still does not work on iOS. It *does* work on my desktop browsers.

Here's the relevant code:

```css
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}

.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(faceless.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(legendary.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(faceless.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(legendary.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(faceless.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(legendary.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    animation-delay: 18s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    animation-delay: 24s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    animation-delay: 30s; 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s; 
}

.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-opacity: 0;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.05);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { 
  opacity: 0 
  -webkit-opacity: 0 
 }
}
```

```html
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Image 02</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Image 03</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Image 04</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Image 05</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Image 06</span>
        <div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For versions of iOS older than 9, you need to prefix your `@keyframes` with `-webkit-`, and include the `-webkit-`prefixed animations and transitions there, instead of including them in your original `@keyframes`:

```css
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
```

becomes:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
```

and so on.

Comment: I've tried all these things but still not working, I'm changing content at specific intervals. Tested on iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 15).
@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% { -webkit-content:"5"; }
  34% { -webkit-content: "7"; }
  67% { -webkit-content: "9"; }
  100% { -webkit-content: "5"; }
}

Comment: @ShihabEK `content` is not a vendor-prefixed property. It's also only valid on pseudo-elements.

Comment: @TylerH, Thank you for sharing your solution with us but it did not work for me.

Comment: @AbhishekRaj iOS has supported unprefixed keyframes since version 9.

Answer (score -2):

Did you use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` elsewhere? Try to delete it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.