# CSS Animation wont start on iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, animation, css-animations

I have the following animation that is triggered every time a page is loaded. Basically, huge dots cover all the screen, and they will became smaller until disappearing. Its working perfectly fine in all devices but, on Iphone, using Chrome or Safari, when I click to the browsers back arrow, the previous page is loaded and the animation is not trigged. What might be the problem?

```
.dott{
      animation: load-dotts-fadeout .4s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation: load-dotts-fadeout .4s ease-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: .3s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
    }
@keyframes load-dotts-fadeout {
  0% {transform:scale(3.3);}
  100% {transform:scale(0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes load-dotts-fadeout {
  0% {-webkit-transform:scale(3.3);}
  100% {-webkit-transform:scale(0);}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My CSS animations are not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400527/my-css-animations-are-not-working-in-ios)

Comment: I already did that in my code.