# Any idea why this easing-function is not working?

Tags: css, animation

I'm using the `cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.56, 0.64, 1)` function in my CSS which should give the effect demonstrated [here](https://easings.net/#easeOutBack), which it does in Chrome and Firefox, however, the easing function doesn't work as expected on IOS, no "bouncing back" effect can be observed.

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks.

UPDATE: The behavior has been observed with the `transform` property.

Comment: When I test this on my iOS device here: https://cubic-bezier.com/#.34,1.56,.64,1, it works perfectly fine. We will need more context, like your actual implementation, to see what's going on. Provide us with your actual code, not somebody else's. Update: it even works on your link when I tap the graph on my iPhone. We might also need to know what device and OS version you are testing with.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see the code implementation as well to help you debug your problem. [My CSS animations are not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29400527/) - Someone wrote on how to fix CSS animation for the iOS. You might be able to see what can you improve in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some experimentation, I've found the following:

- **Webkit** doesn't produce the "bouncing" effect with certain properties, of which one is the `transform` property. However, The easing function works well with offset-properties(`top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`)
- **Blink**, on the other hand, produces the effect with both `transform` and offset-properties.