# Having trouble with CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, css-animations

I have the following snippet:

```js
//Skills Animation On View
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  function callback(observations, observer) {
    observations.forEach(observation => {
      if (observation.isIntersecting) { //IF IT'S IN VIEW
        observation.target.classList.add('animated');
        observation.target.classList.add('animated1');
      } else {
        observation.target.classList.remove('animated');
        observation.target.classList.remove('animated1');
      }
    });
  }

  // CREATE AN INTERSECTION OBSERVER
  let options = {
    root: null, //null means it will observe on the viewport
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0 //1 means the whole element needs to be viewable before we animate it
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

  // NOW PUT THE OBSERVER ON EACH OF THE ELEMENTS WE WANT TO ANIMATE WHEN IT'S IN VIEW
  let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    observer.observe(spans[i]);
  }
  let spans1 = document.querySelectorAll('line');
  for (let a = 0; a < spans1.length; a++) {
    observer.observe(spans1[a]);
  }
});
```

```css
.master {
  display: flex;
}

.master div {
  width: 98.6%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .master div {
    width: 99.9%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .master {
    flex-flow: wrap;
  }
}

.column-adjustment {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row-adjustment::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.skill-bars {
  padding: 25px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .skill-bars {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

.skill-bars .bar {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.skill-bars .bar:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.skill-bars .bar .info {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skill-bars .bar .info span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skill-bars .bar .progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.bar .progress-line span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}

.bar .progress-line span.animated {
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line.html span {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.css span {
  width: 92%;
}

.bar .progress-line.jquery span {
  width: 91%;
}

.bar .progress-line.python span {
  width: 83%;
}

.progress-line span.animated::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line span.animated::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line.html span::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.css span::after {
  content: "92%";
}

.progress-line.jquery span::after {
  content: "91%";
}

.progress-line.python span::after {
  content: "83%";
}

.skill-bars .bar .info line {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1s linear forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line line {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  background: black;
}

.bar .progress-line line.animated {
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line.html line {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.css line {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.jquery line {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.python line {
  width: 90%;
}

.bar .progress-line.mysql line {
  width: 92%;
}

.progress-line line.animated::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line line.animated::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress-line.css line::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.jquery line::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.python line::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.mysql line::after {
  content: "92%";
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="column-adjustment" data-aos="fade-right">
    <div class="row-adjustment">
      <div class="skill-bars">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <span>Example 1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line html">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <span>Example 2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line css">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <span>Example 3</span>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line jquery">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <span>Example 4</span>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line python">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- second box -->
  <div class="column-adjustment" data-aos="fade-left">
    <div class="row-adjustment">
      <div class="skill-bars">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <line>Example 5</line>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line css">
            <line></line>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <line>Example 6</line>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line jquery">
            <line></line>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <line>Example 7</line>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line python">
            <line></line>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="info">
            <line>Example 8</line>
          </div>
          <div class="progress-line mysql">
            <line></line>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is that this seems to work perfectly on web-pages, Android devices...etc, but it fails to work properly on iOS devices, since on iPhone 14, it produces the following:

[image]

Any ideas why this issue is only occuring on iOS devices, but works fine on other devices?

I tried following this post: [My CSS animations are not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400527/my-css-animations-are-not-working-in-ios) and adding `web-kit` but it still didnt fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are animating (pseudo) children of observed elements, making observed elements wide enough to exceed viewport (**in Safari**), what makes them no longer fulfil the `threshold: 1` condition, what removes the class and shrinks them back, effectively resulting in infinite loop.

At least it is behaviour that is reproducible in my Firefox if I make **viewport very narrow**.

For confirming this I'd try to

- decrease the threshold to `0.0` and see if it makes any difference,
- add debug outline to all observed elements to see when (if) they exceed viewport,
- add `console.count('intersecting')` into `observation.isIntersecting` branch to see if it is not matched "too often".

Comment: So to fix it, do I have the decrease the threshold? Also, can you confirm what class you are referring to?

Comment: are you referring to `scaleX`?

Comment: I meant changing `threshold: 1.0` to `threshold: 0`, or removing it completely since zero is the default value.

Comment: Sorry, im unable to get you, I don't have a threshold property. Are you referring to the Meta tag?

Comment: No, property of `options` object in the function passed to the event listener. In JavaScript.